# work winth cassandra on centos

Tags: django, centos, cassandra, cql

I have a problem when I want to work with cassandra in centos
Every thins is right, I have installed Python,DJango and cassadnra on it but when I want ro un my project I have an error in importing cqlengine to my project.
Can any one help me about it.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade python on your centos box. It looks like you're using python 2.6 on your centos box. Set comprehensions (what's happening in the cqlengine file) were not introduced until python 2.7. That's most likely your problem.